# Update-manager not working due to 404 error

Tags: update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

I have the following error

```
Failed to Download repository information
Check your Internet connection..

W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-stable/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-stable/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system has a PPA that doesn't exist.

There is no Firefox-stable PPA for Oneric, as the latest Firefox is already in the main repos. You will need to remove this PPA from your Software Sources.

Please, look at these questions: [How can PPAs be removed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed), and [How to remove a repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43345/how-to-remove-a-repository)