# Is Apt-get Update Lag Related to Google Chrome?

Tags: apt, google-chrome, repository

I have Google Chrome installed from the [Google Chrome repository](http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/). When I run `sudo apt-get update`, I notice that getting headers relating to Google Chrome takes more time than is needed to get all the other headers.

I thought it was normal but today I came across an (old) [bug page](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=38608) that initially suggested use of `sudo apt-get -o Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth=0 update` instead of the basic `sudo apt-get update` and later stated that the problem was fixed (**by April 2010**). However, I feel I'm currently having the same problem: the process rapidly completes  ~97% in under 5 sec but the remaining ~3%, involving the Google Chrome headers, takes a couple of minutes or so more. Using `sudo apt-get -o Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth=0 update` doesn't significantly improve things.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10, fully updated.

**Edit on 20120502**

Just an observation: I updated to `18.0.1025.168 (Official Build 134367)` and left the ppa ticked but it doesn't seem to be a problem now. I see: `Fetched 6,385 kB in 2min 31s (42.0 kB/s)`.

Comment: i temporarily black-listed google because of that. I thought it was me.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "black-listed". Could you clarify? What I have done by way of a workaround, is to go into Update Manager, Settings, Software Sources, Other Software and to **un**-check the line corresponding to Google Chrome. `sudo apt-get update` now is done in ~ 6 sec. This means that I'll have to refer to http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com or other tech sites to know when an update is available and then temporarily undo the change in Update Manager.

Comment: You did the right thing. By "black-listing" I meant the exact thing you just did. It's a pain but until GOOGLE gets a faster server I suppose we are stuck with slow updates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a problem with Google's server, the bug is [reported here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=93409).

As outlined many times in that report, there's no need to pollute the bug with +1 or "me too comments" as someone is working on it and that just spams everyone on the bug, clicking the star in the bug report to show it affects you is how you can help.

You can temporarily remove the repository by following these instructions, or you can just untick the box to temporarily disable it:

- [How to remove a repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43345/how-to-remove-a-repository)

However this also means you won't get Chrome updates, so what I do is disable it and then  reenable it once a week or so to check for updates.

Answer (score 0):

With Chrome PPA, I recently experienced very slow downloads not only of headers, but of the main update package, at few KB/s of speed, and the process took a very long time. So I think it's a problem of Google's PPA server.

Finally I moved to Chromium [chromium-browser](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/chromium-browser), I suggest you to evaluate it as an alternative. It is in the Universe Ubuntu repository, so you don't have do add any PPA, and you have normal download speed (and many mirrors!).

Here the full "Chromium vs Chrome" page:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ChromiumBrowserVsGoogleChrome

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your experience is different than mine. The actual download of the update, when it is available, is _not_ slower than other downloads for me. I'm aware of the Chromium vs Chrome issue and that's being argued endlessly.