# How to remove (purge) Opera PPA?

Tags: ppa, opera

I'm completely as a loss as to how to get rid of all Opera packages.

I have ppa-purge installed, but don't know what to specify for the ppa.. I have tried the following:

```
sudo ppa-purge deb.opera.com
sudo ppa-purge deb.opera.com/opera
sudo ppa-purge deb.opera.com/opera stable
sudo ppa-purge opera-list
sudo ppa-purge -p http://deb.opera.com/opera stable
```

..and many other combinations of the above, and all result in something like:

Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: stable http://deb.opera.com/opera/

This seems a lot harder than it could be to just uninstall (and completely remove) an application.  Ideally I'd open the software center, remove Opera and then it could ask me 'also remove the repository?' and then it'd be gone.

Answer (score 4):

PPA purge only works if you've installed a PPA (from ppa.launchpad.net). In order to remove it you need to manually remove the line from `/etc/apt/sources.list`

- [How to remove a repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43345/how-to-remove-a-repository)

If a repository is leaving junk around you don't want, you can [synaptic [image: Install synaptic]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic) and click the Origin button:

[image]

Then click on the filter on the left that shows the repository, then you can select them and remove them from there. If you've already removed the repository the packages might be listed under "Local".

As far as to why Opera isn't in the Software Center, people need to tell them to submit it to the Software Center so people don't have to do this kind of thing by hand.

Comment: So it can't be used for other software that is distributed and kept updated through an apt repository?  Is there another way to get rid of everything that was installed through a particular repository prior to removing the file from /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ ? (or sources.list) ?

Answer (score 0):

I had opera from there website try downloading the .deb file an use gdebi (sudo apt-get install gdebi) to remove the package

Just right click the deb then open with gdebi if the package is installed you can re-install or remove.

I did it this way and have no trace of opera (I can see in day to day use at least)

Hope that helps...