# ppa-purge cound not find package list

Tags: apt, ppa

I need to downgrade pipewire, for some reason `ppa-purge` could not find the PPA, I've followed the instructions [in this repo](https://github.com/pipewire-debian/pipewire-debian) to install both pipewire and wireplumber.

```
$ file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pipewire-debian-ubuntu-*
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pipewire-debian-ubuntu-pipewire-upstream-focal.list:         ASCII text
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pipewire-debian-ubuntu-pipewire-upstream-focal.list.save:    ASCII text
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pipewire-debian-ubuntu-wireplumber-upstream-focal.list:      ASCII text
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pipewire-debian-ubuntu-wireplumber-upstream-focal.list.save: ASCII text


$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pipewire-debian-ubuntu-pipewire-upstream-focal.list
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream/ubuntu focal main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream/ubuntu focal main


$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream                           
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: pipewire-debian pipewire-upstream
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: pipewire-debian pipewire-upstream
```

**EDIT:** my question was marked as duplicated of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168195/how-to-remove-purge-opera-ppa). I'm not sure how is this related, I need to downgrade a package not remove the repo!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the repository server:

```
$ sudo ppa-purge -s ppa.launchpad.net ppa:pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream
```

(I don't know why but the default is ppa.launchpadcontent.net)