# Trouble getting updates Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

Could someone help me decipher why I am getting this issue? I've tried updating my packages several times and I always get this same message with the update manager.

Things I've already checked:

- I am connected to the internet (as shown by my being able to post this question)
- All other internet related things work fine, USC etc.
- I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on a HP pavillion dv6000, not dual booting.

Here's a screenshot of my problem, have I missed a crucial update? I'd not have thought so seeing as it's been roughly a week during which I didn't turn on my laptop, but if anyone has any idea/suggestions I'd be grateful for any input.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PPA mentioned in the error is the root cause of this error. Remove this PPA annd try to update again. Try the following in terminal:

```
sudo ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

Here you should see a file named crebs.list (or something like that). This PPA is included in your source lists. Remove it using the following command:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/crebs.list
```

**Alternate:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:crebs/ppa
```

Source: [My article at Make Tech Easier](http://maketecheasier.com/fix-the-package-information-was-last-updated-days-ago-error-in-ubuntu/2012/06/22).

It also gives the GUI way to fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have added a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/crebs/) whose link has since broken, see "[How to remove a repository](https://askubuntu.com/q/43345/506)" on how to get rid of the PPA.