# /var/lib/apt/lists is huge

Tags: apt, package-management

I've noticed that `/var/lib/apt/lists` is HUGE. It's as large as 86MB. Which seems a little too big. Is this normal? If not, what should I do?

Comment: Ya that's huge. Mine is 1GB

Answer (score 73, accepted):

When you run `sudo apt-get update` (or use the Refresh button in a package manager), a list of packages will get downloaded from the Ubuntu servers. These files are then stored in `/var/lib/apt/lists/`.

You can safely remove the contents of that directory as it is recreated when you refresh the package lists. If you remove the files, but do not run `apt-get update` to fetch the lists, commands like `apt-cache` will fail to provide information (since the cache is empty).

To shrink the directory and speed up fetching package lists, consider disabling some repositories that you do not need (see [How to remove a repository?](https://askubuntu.com/q/43345/6969)). This includes PPAs (see also [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/q/307/6969))

Answer (score 21):

If you feel like that, then try with this command:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Will this be safe? Do those lists only contain packages that could be installed and not the installed ones?

Comment: @thabubble yes it is , it will recreate the cache information of your source.there is no harm with this . I am sure .

Comment: So why is it not in /var/cache/ ?

Comment: After I used sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* I have problems with sudo apt-get update it says: E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ InRelease' is not signed. Does that mean the lists were not recovered?

Answer (score 2):

Mine is 142M, so i guess it's normal.

The reason can be because /var/lib/apt/lists/ is the storage area for state information for each package resource specified in sources.list

Comment: It may be so large. But this is a newly installed system@642MB. Those lists take up almost 1/6 of the space. And that is huge.

Comment: 642Mb s very small for an Ubuntu installation. My root filesystem (not including any user or data files) is 14Gb. /var/lib/apt/lists is 123Mb. On a second system the values are 5.3Gb and 87Mb,

Comment: Yes. Ubuntu recomends 5 GB of hard-drive space minimum

Comment: Mine is 43 Gigabyte