# Ubuntu 12.04 Root Filesystem Full

Tags: boot, filesystem

My root filesystem seems to be full even though my /home directory still has a lot of space.

Output from df -h:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg0-root   19G   18G  144M 100% /
udev                  1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                 385M  960K  384M   1% /run
none                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                  1.9G  176K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/mapper/vg0-log   9.3G   49M  8.8G   1% /var/log
/dev/sda1             447M   86M  337M  21% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg0-home  261G  7.5G  241G   4% /home
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove or hide old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)

Comment: Forgot to add I am unable to boot to the latest kernel and must use a previous kernel I have

Comment: Remove old kernels and you will get space.

Comment: Why is /var/log/ on a partition? If due to sql ... why is sql not on a partition? If due to a mail/print server I'd go looking there to  make some room (cups can be told to keep all old prints on disk).

Answer (score 1):

This distribution of your disk is telling you that the root dir (`/`) is on a partition and the home directories (`/home`) are on other one, separated from the first. So if the root directory is full, won't use the home directories because they're different partitions.

So, I recommend to clean up, for example, old installed packages. apt always stores the downloaded packages (.deb), and maybe you could free a bit of space. And also the old kernels. I use [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com) to do both.

Another idea I have is to change the size of the root partition.

Answer (score 0):

According to "Mounted on" you keep "everything interesting" but /home and /var/log in your root partition. That would include directories like /var/lib/mysql or /var/lib/postgresql/*/data, which can get quite large.

I'd try the following:

```
cd /
du -sh *
```

and then dig into the "large directories" until you've found the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post: 
[/var/lib/apt/lists huge in 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179955/var-lib-apt-lists-huge-in-12-04?newreg=90acdfe6d4184ae194895a9a0879f904)

I had a similar problem. My `/var/lib/apt/lists/` was full of packages. The following commands solved my problem:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```