# Unable to locate package docker-engine

Tags: 14.04, docker

I'm trying to install docker on Ubuntu in vmware, unsuccessfully.
These are the commands and errors I experience.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install docker-engine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package docker-engine
```

Comment: Make sure you have installed the prerequisites for your Ubuntu version. Then, install Docker.

Comment: I already followed the steps in prerequisites       sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)

Comment: Have you created `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list` and add the correct deb entries for your Ubuntu?

Comment: Thanks, earlier it is unable to create the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list  after trying & trying finally it got created and successfully installed the docker in my machine....    thanks again.......!

Comment: Actually I am having the same issue although .../docker.list is correct 
avi@guest-Inspiron-1464:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list

deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main

avi@guest-Inspiron-1464:~$ apt-cache policy docker-engine

N: Unable to locate package docker-engine

Comment: perform all the actions (commands) as root, otherwise it wont create properly --  once again follow the steps from starting in docs in docker site : https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/ubuntulinux/

Comment: I've added sources, also have tried to use Docker's shell script to install all automatically, but still got E: Unable to locate package docker-engine for all cases...

Comment: @praveen Did you call `sudo apt-get update` *after* modifying `docker.list`? That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 13):

Try 'uname -a' and make sure you're running a 64-bit architecture:

Docker requires a 64-bit installation regardless of your Ubuntu version.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/

Comment: Could you explain a little about what uname is and why it would help?

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the comments, you have to

1. find out your distribution name via `lsb_release -c`
2. the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list` should have the following content (and nothing else): `deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-VERSION-NAME main`

In my case (Ubuntu 14.04 aka 'trusty') I added `deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-trusty main`

Comment: Look at https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/ where there are detailed instructions on setting up apt and related keys to get docker. I had it installed via docker.io (the package maintained by ubuntu) which left me with an unresolved docker-engine package trying to install nvidia-docker. I had to uninstall and purge docker.io before getting docker-engine installed.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by running **apt-get update** followed by **apt-get install docker.io**

Answer (score 0):

I had other issues including "Unable" in Ubuntu 16.04. This is bash script to solve issues in my machine.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt update
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin

VERSION-NAME=$(lsb_release -c)
y=$(echo $VERSION-NAME | awk '{print $2}')
echo $y
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
touch docker_test.list
echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-$y main" > docker_test.list

sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker.io
```

I had different issue when I had to uninstall Docker at the time. This is bash script ([source](http://steronius.blogspot.com/2017/11/dpkg-error-processing-package-dockerio_18.html)) for my machine.

```
# For unistall in Ubuntu
sudo apt-get purge docker.io 
# This will erase all your container images
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
# This will erase all docker configs
sudo rm -rf /etc/docker/
sudo apt-get purge docker.io
```

Comment: Is it OK, that sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* would remove all other lists I added earlier (ppa.launchpad.net for PHP, etc...)?

Comment: @Roman that is good point. I didn't have "ppa.launchpad.net" in the folder. In your case, please backup the "lists" folder and try my method. If something going bad, you could recover. By the way, according to Lekensteyn, the folder is safe to be cleaned (ref: https://askubuntu.com/a/179992/789450)