# Error while looking for updates

Tags: 12.04, apt, updates, ppa

Everytime I try to check for new updates, I always get this error message :

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And I get a message telling me to check my internet connection, I am connected via WiFi to internet. What's the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PPA `ppa:pmcenery/ppa` "*PPA for Paul McEnery*" doesn't contain any packages for Precise so you can't use it.

Remove it from your software sources. See [How to remove a repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43345/how-to-remove-a-repository) if you don't know how to do this.