# Can't update software

Tags: updates, burg

I can't update because:

W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bean123ch/burg/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

WHAT CAN I DO?

Comment: W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bean123ch/burg/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bean123ch/burg/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bean123ch/burg/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to retrieve `/bean123ch/burg/ubuntu/dists` quantal but it  does not exist

Only `/bean123ch/burg/ubuntu/dists/` hardy or  jaunty or lucid or  maverick exist

### Solution

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes`

`sudo burg-install "(hd0)"`

replacing (hd0) with the drive on which your MBR is installed.

`sudo update-burg`

Comment: They may need to remove the offending repo http://askubuntu.com/questions/43345/how-to-remove-a-repository

Comment: It works to get back the burg theme. but the Ubuntu system doesn't update. I get the same text. please help me

Comment: Did you try the answers on the link wojox provided? Are you saying burg now works but you are still getting W:Failed to fetch `ppa.launchpad.net/bean123ch/burg/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/… 404 Not Found`