# update error in ppa

Tags: updates, ppa

In `sudo apt-get update`, I see this error

```
( W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/multimedia/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages 
 404  Not Found).
```

How to solve my problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove that repository as it no longer exists.

Here is a related question that should help you

[How to remove a repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43345/how-to-remove-a-repository)

Answer (score 0):

The ppa does not provide packages for trusty. Take a look at your url

[http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/multimedia/ubuntu/dists/](http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/multimedia/ubuntu/dists/.)

To hide/resolve the error, you should remove the ppa from Software Sources. I recommend using Y PPA Manager, it is handy.

If you need to install the packages provided by the ppa for trusty, you can check to see whether you can forcibly use a package from older distributions provided they work.

Comment: In yppa manager, I have many PPA : ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 (trusty), ppa:otto-kesselgulash/gimp (tusty ), ppa:ubuntu-mm/ppa (tusty),  ppa:upubuntu-commultimedia (tusty),  ppa:webupd8team/java (tusty), ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager (tusty), ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa (tusty) .  Should i remove  ppa: upubuntu-com/multimedia (tusty) ?

Comment: Yes, you could if that is the only ppa that is not yet updated for trusty. You can remove a ppa using "Remove" or "Purge". Remove will just remove the ppa, while Purge while potentially downgrade packages installed from that ppa.