# How can I remove this PPA?

Tags: ppa

I have just installed a personal package archive from NodeSource by running

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
```

I would like to know how to remove this. After looking at other answers, I tried without success:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:nodesource
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a repository?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43345/how-to-remove-a-repository)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can PPAs be removed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

Comment: I strongly suggest looking at the 'dupe' I've identified - it shows the `ppa-purge` command that is 'safer' than `add-apt-repository --remove`

Comment: `ppa-purge` marks the repository as inactive, so removing it later is not required.

Comment: You full answer is [here][1]. On www.askubuntu.com


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed

Answer (score 0):

Open the Ubuntu dash and search "Software & Updates". In Software & Updates click on the "Other Software" tab and look for the PPA called "https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.10". It should look like this: [image]

Click on it to select it and then click remove.