# "Repository not signed" after uninstall

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, playonlinux, gnupg

Iam a severe beginner, so please bear with me ...

I un-installed playonlinux from my machine*. Now, whenever running `sudo apt-get update`, the system still prints these warnings:

> W: GPG error: http://deb.playonlinux.com precise InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 73F0D6E88E3D6C3A
>
> W: The repository 'http://deb.playonlinux.com precise InRelease' is not signed.
>
> N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.

When I look at sources.list, it does not contain any reference to playonlinux that I can identify. I also ran `apt-key update`. When I try to `purge` playonlinux, it says that *Package 'playonlinux' is not installed*.

How can I fix this? Thanks!

*I am running Elementary OS 0.4.1. (Built on "Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS").

Comment: [Here's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey) how you can usually fix the error, but in this case you will probably want to [remove the repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43345/how-to-remove-a-repository). Please note that elementary OS and other non-Ubuntu systems are not on topic here...

Comment: @Wilf Thanks for your help, removing worked! I figured since elementary is based on Ubuntu it would fit here, but point taken.

Comment: @patrick please look on Unix and Linux for further guidence. It seems you are already a member of U&L.