# Can't remove repository

Tags: apt, lubuntu, ppa

i've tried to install wine-mono 4.7.1  on Lubuntu 17.10

```
wget http://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-mono/4.7.1
sudo apt update
```

Result:

```
Hit:1 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease
Get:2 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease [78,6 kB]   
Get:3 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease [72,2 kB] 
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease [78,6 kB]    
Hit:5 http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu xenial InRelease            
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cdemu/ppa/ubuntu artful InRelease               
Ign:7 http://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-mono/4.7.1 artful InRelease               
Err:8 http://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-mono/4.7.1 artful Release                 
404  Not Found
Hit:9 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu artful InRelease                
Hit:10 http://deb.playonlinux.com trusty InRelease                             
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-mono/4.7.1 artful Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I look [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed/310#310)

The "sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:" command didn't work for me.

Tried manually remove  from /etc/apt/sources.list but access is denied

Is there other way to remove the broken repository

Comment: Can't you uncheck it from the Software & Updates in the Other Software tab?

Comment: when you tried to manually remove it from the sources.list file did you use `sudo`  (to raise your privileges/permissions) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed) and [How to remove a repository?](https://askubuntu.com/q/43345)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wget` command does not add a ppa in the first place, it simply downloads files over http. The command you posted simply downloads Wine from the internet.

However, if you find you would like to remove a source manually, you can do so by opening `/etc/apt/sources.list` and removing the line that contains the source.

You can do this using the command `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`. Sudo is used as you require root privileges to edit the file.

Answer (score -1):

The command to download mono is:

```
wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine/wine-mono/4.7.1/wine-mono-4.7.1.msi
```

then you have to run it in the WINE prefix that you want to install mono in.

To correct the sources list, you need root privileges:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```