# Unable to update Ubuntu

Tags: apt, updates, ppa

I'm quite new to Ubuntu and has just had this error when trying to use the update command. Would anyone be be able to help me solve this?

Thank you!

```
~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for alastair: 
Ign:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nvbn-rm/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nvbn-rm/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release               
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease       
Hit:7 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease     
Hit:8 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/nvbn-rm/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Are you able to provide a bit more info. Have you added a custom source location in the apt sources.list?  It looks like that one repository is using the wrong address.

Comment: If you go to that address in a browser there to file for bionic. I can't say for sure but maybe that repository never had anything for the bionic release. It looks like the packages there haven't been updated since 2015, the link provided above has details of a way to get rid of repositories so that should sort it for you.

Comment: Hi guys, I just followed the instructions in the given link but that didn't seem to solve the problem as I got the same error after I tried to update again after that.

Comment: I don't think that I have added any custom sources, but perhaps I have without even realizing. Is there a quick way to check that?

I see what you mean about the repository link, I don't know how I would go about replacing it that though.

Comment: All those PPAs you added are custom sources.

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the launchpad links from [Softwares and Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viZvk.png) as per this link: [How to remove a repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43345/how-to-remove-a-repository) and that seems to have worked for now.