# Can't install mariadb-server - unmet dependancy mariadb-server

Tags: 20.04, mariadb

I was following a setup process of the ERPNext from [here](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-erpnext-open-source-erp-on-ubuntu-17-04-22771) in a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 server but I'm stuck at command `sudo apt -y install mariadb-server libmysqlclient-dev` as I can't install mariadb in it.

The issue is

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.6 (>= 1:10.6.4+maria~hirsute) but it is not going to be installed
```

It was initially showing `mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server` only, then I followed some answers available on this website so it was changed to `mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.3` and after following the official site's [instructions](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#distro=Ubuntu&distro_release=focal--ubuntu_focal&mirror=ossplanet&version=10.6), it is now at `...10.6`.

I've searched and looked on almost all questions and answers available on this website as well as on other websites, none helped. Also, I've tried installing the `mariadb-server-client` as suggested by the CLI but it didn't work either, I've tried installing the `mariadb-server-core` again as suggested by the CLI and it installed successfully but didn't help in installation of `mariadb-server`.

Comment: Hmmm. The ERPNext instructions are ancient (17.04! Last updated in 2018!) and seem likely to have led you badly astray. Undo everything that those instructions told you to do. Most 20.04 users can install MariaDB Server 10.3 from the Ubuntu repositories with a single command: `sudo apt install mariadb-server` *and nothing else*. No other sources, no keys, no haywiring, nothing. If you need a specific version of MariaDB, you should say so in your Question above. If you need the newest version of all software, then you shouldn't be using an LTS release.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks for the tip, I removed the repositories instead of undoing everything and it worked. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Why it happened?** The old versions of Ubuntu required the repository of `mariadb` to be added first before installing it. Now in 20.04, it's not required and the installation works directly, but as I followed an old tutorial, I added the repositories which caused the issue, so, the solution is to remove the repositories added.

**The solution:** So, as @user535733 suggested to undo everything, I looked at the instructions and found one repository of `mariadb` that I had added (using `add-apt-repository` command) but I had also added another one from mariadb's official site to install it.

So, the easy way was to remove these added repositories and for that I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/345473/877064) answer and typed a command `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and removed all the repositories containing `mariadb` and the installation of `mariadb` worked.