# Unable to install mariadb-server on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: mariadb

I followed [this article](https://upcloud.com/community/tutorials/installing-lamp-stack-ubuntu/) to install mariadb on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. However, I was shown these messages

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree     
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.3 (>= 1:10.3.34-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Thus, I couldn't start the server or check its status. I've tried to remove repos of mariadb as [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1362435/cant-install-mariadb-server-unmet-dependancy-mariadb-server) suggested, but no repos available. What should I do?

UPDATED: When I use `sudo apt update`, the following appear

```
Hit:1 http://vn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://vn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://vn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree     
Reading state information... Done
10 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Comment: Hello. Please do not show pictures of text. Always cut and paste the text into the body of the question.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Please edit your Question above to include the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: @user535733 Hi there. I added the output of that command line.

Comment: `10 packages can be upgraded`. Run `sudo apt upgrade`. If there are any errors, post the entire output. If there are no errors, then try installing `mariadb-server` again.

Answer (score 0):

https://mariadb.org/download/?t=repo-config&d=21.04+%22hirsute%22&v=10.5&r_m=23Media
Please note - MariaDB 10.3 is not for Ubuntu 20.04 and above. Please try to install MariaDB 10.6 - it works smoothly.

Comment: "Not for" is incorrect. The default version of MariaDB on Ubuntu is 10.3 : https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/mariadb-10.3. Your link is to v21, not 20. v20 updates to 10.4+ are here: https://mariadb.org/download/?t=repo-config&d=20.04+%22focal%22