# How to remove a artifactory repository?

Tags: apache2

I have this repository https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/couchdb-deb that is preventing me to update the system, what is the easiest way to remove it? I have tried using PPA purge but not being a PPA repo I can't remove it by using those recommendations.

Doing `grep -r 'apache\.jfrog' /etc/apt/sources.list*` I get:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchdb.list.distUpgrade:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/couchdb-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/couchdb-deb/ groovy main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchdb.list:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/couchdb-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/couchdb-deb/ groovy main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchdb.list.save:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/couchdb-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/couchdb-deb/ groovy main
```

Comment: What is your problem with the [Duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file) commented to your [earlier very same question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1363915/unable-to-update-to-a-supported-newer-version-or-to-do-simple-update)?

Comment: That is not a PPA repository and the same answers won't work

Comment: So you can go to the second answer? https://askubuntu.com/a/1087463/631600

Comment: Tried it, there's not the repo I am looking for there.

Comment: Then you don't have this repository and it may not be the problem. See also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43345/how-to-remove-a-repository).

Comment: So, why do I get the message "The repository 'https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/couchdb-deb groovy Release' does not have a Release file."  when I am trying to update? I do updates both from the terminal and the software update programs

Comment: I understand that the repository that you are using is not named with the 'ppa' convention, but it is a package archive.  Open `Software and Updates` and look in the 'Other Software` tab - you will find it in the list somewhere.  Uncheck the box next to it, to disable it.

Comment: Checked there for the past 2 days, there is nothing even close to either 'apache' 'jfrog' 'artifactory' 'couchdb'. Still stuck.

Comment: Sorry, but this **should** work. And if not, I'm afraid we cannot help here, because you are using an unsupported Ubuntu (EOL). Backup your data and reinstall a supported version is my advice.

Comment: Last idea. Please edit your question and add the output of `grep -rn 'apache\.jfrog' /etc/apt/sources.list*`

Comment: run `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchdb.list` then `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade`, then you can follow this -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems that I am now on a much better place!!!! Trying to do all the updates and then will upgrade the system. Your patience and help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why the [usual way to disable a repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43345/how-to-remove-a-repository) does not work for you is unclear for me.

However, you can

1. Find the file where the repository is set:

   ```
   grep -rn 'apache\.jfrog' /etc/apt/sources.list*
   ```

   Output can be something like:

   ```
   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchdb.list:2:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/couchdb-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/couchdb-deb/ groovy main
   ```

   This means, the repository is set in the second line of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchdb.list`.

   Note, only files named `*.list` need to be considered.
2. Comment out the respective line

   ```
   sudo sed -i '2s/^/# /' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchdb.list
   ```

   **or** remove the file, if you're sure that it does not list any other repositories that are needed.

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchdb.list
   ```
3. Update/Upgrade your system

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade
   ```
4. Then you can update to a supported release, following answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release).