# Remove all manually installed libraries

Tags: apt, 22.04, application-development, libraries

What is the easiest way to remove all development library packages that have been installed manually, i.e. via `apt-get install libsomelib-dev`, on Ubuntu 22.04?

Something like:

```
sudo apt-get remove lib*-dev
```

But excluding those libraries that are needed for other programs. The above command causes a lot of applications and essential system packages to be removed as well - that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Since you do not even state what version of Ubuntu you are using it would be very hard to make any suggestion. I do believe what you want can not be done but maybe someone else knows.

Comment: @David Added Ubuntu version to the question, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove a repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43345/how-to-remove-a-repository)

Comment: I won't include this as an answer because I don't intend to test it on my system, but: `apt-mark showmanual | grep -e "^lib.*-dev"` will get you a list of all manually-installed packages the name of which starts with "lib" and end with "-dev". I think feeding that into `apt remove` will get you what you're after. `apt remove $(apt-mark showmanual | grep -e "^lib.*-dev")`may be what you're looking for.