# The following packages have been kept back: libllvm15:i386

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.10

Every time I try to upgrade, I get this message.

Input: `sudo apt upgrade`

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libllvm15:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Input: `apt-cache policy libllvm15`

Output:

```
libllvm15:
  Installed: 1:15.0.2-1
  Candidate: 1:15.0.2-1
  Version table:
 *** 1:15.0.2-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Input: `apt-cache policy libllvm15:i386`

Output:

```
libllvm15:i386:
  Installed: 1:15.0.2-1
  Candidate: 1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.10.1
  Version table:
     1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.10.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-proposed/main i386 Packages
 *** 1:15.0.2-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Input: `sudo apt upgrade`

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libllvm15:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gnome-characters
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 467 kB of archives.
After this operation, 24,6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-proposed/main amd64 gnome-characters amd64 43.1-0ubuntu1 [467 kB]
Fetched 467 kB in 1s (365 kB/s)            
(Reading database ... 273496 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-characters_43.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-characters (43.1-0ubuntu1) over (43.0-1) ...
Setting up gnome-characters (43.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.74.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Scanning processes...                                                           
Scanning processor microcode...                                                 
Scanning linux images...                                                        

Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.

The processor microcode seems to be up-to-date.

No services need to be restarted.

No containers need to be restarted.

No user sessions are running outdated binaries.

No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host.
```

Input: `sudo apt update`

Output:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports InRelease [99,9 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease [109 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-proposed InRelease [267 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates/main amd64 Packages [149 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates/main i386 Packages [73,4 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [22,5 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates/universe i386 Packages [57,1 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [79,9 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [33,6 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1.120 B]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5.392 B]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1.428 B]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-proposed/universe amd64 Packages [44,5 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-proposed/universe Translation-en [21,0 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-proposed/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3.424 B]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-proposed/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [780 B]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-proposed/main amd64 Packages [114 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-proposed/main Translation-en [32,6 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-proposed/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [53,8 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-proposed/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [1.600 B]
Hit:24 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                          
Hit:25 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Hit:26 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:27 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kicad/kicad-6.0-releases/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Hit:23 https://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/stable xenial InRelease        
Fetched 1.279 kB in 9s (144 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

And everytime I use:

```
sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade
```

I got into `tty` mode and I have to `install ubuntu-desktop` again by using `aptitude install` not by `apt install.`

Comment: Thank you, I have edited it

Comment: Next, please edit your question to show the complete output of `sudo apt update` and of `sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: I have added both

Comment: `apt-cache policy libllvm15:i386` please.

Comment: done, I have added this

Answer (score 2):

Your `apt-cache policy` output shows that you are installing packages from the `kinetic-proposed` repository.

"-proposed" repositories are only for testing. Packages in those repositories may be broken. They may not be compatible with the rest of your system. They are NOT recommended for daily use. They are not enabled on a stock install of Ubuntu -- a human made that change.

Disable the `kinetic-proposed` repository.

Then run `sudo apt update`, because your sources just changed.

Comment: Thank you so much for yout fast answer, Can you tell me how i could disbale kinetic-proposed repository. ?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/43349/19626 for one easy way to disable a repository.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error and it's because Ubuntu decided to NOT to include the update source repos in the default installation (do not ask me why, this is working OK with Debian) ... but anyway, it can be solved easily adding these lines:

```
deb http://ec.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates main restricted
deb http://ec.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates universe
deb http://ec.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic-updates multiverse
```

To a file at the APT configuration with a name like `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/more-ubuntu-sources.list`

> You may change the mirror server to a closer one to you

This is also happening to other versions, so ensure to change kinetic for the release version you are using like focal or jammy

Then run `apt-get update` and you should be good to go and install `libllvm15` and any of the new packages like `gnome-builder`, `libgtk-3-0-dev` and others.