# How to delete a vulkan repository from Ubuntu 18?

Tags: 18.04

How to delete this ubuntu 18 repository?

```
Err:20 https://packages.lunarg.com/vulkan bionic Release
```

404  Not Found [IP: 104.26.1.199 443]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove a repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43345/how-to-remove-a-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open "Software and Sources", go to other software, and remove this particular repository.